# How to import big file sql to mysql locally

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

I want to import a big sql file to mysql database locally .

I try to import it with command line but i execute the command and i waited more than two hours without any results for an 170 Mo sql file .

I tried also to change php.ini but wampserver don't start .

```
memory_limit = 900M
post_max_size = 500M
upload_max_filesize = 500M
```

How can i import my file please ?

Comment: have you restart server after that

Comment: Provide the command line code that you tried. We can able to enhance the code by then

Comment: Your MySQL server will have its own set of limits.  Likely your issue is its `max_allowed_packet` value.

Comment: What is your command line script? If you use the mysql command, you can try the --verbose parameter

Comment: mysql -u username -p password dbname < dump.sql

Comment: Did your import worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following command

> mysql -u username -p password dbname < dump.sql

you do not have to modify your php.ini, you are not using PHP.

You can use this command to display what is going:

```
mysql -u username -p password dbname --verbose < dump.sql
```

Your file is big, it can take a while to load on your local database, it depends of your own computer and for example if the datas loaded have a lot of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Wampserver controls the limits applied to phpMyAdmin from the alias definition for phpMyAdmin

So edit `\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf` it should look like this initially in WAMPserver 2.5

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/"

# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
# Require local
#
# by
#
# Require all granted
#

<Directory "d:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
    Require local
  </IfDefine>
  <IfDefine !APACHE24>
    Order Deny,Allow
      Deny from all
      Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </IfDefine>
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
</Directory>
```

So amend these parameter to increase the limits

```
  php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 128M
  php_admin_value post_max_size 128M
  php_admin_value max_execution_time 360
  php_admin_value max_input_time 360
```

Alternatively you can use the `mysql console` launched from the wampmanager menus like so :-

```
left click wampmanager -> MySQL -> MySQL console
```

If you have not chnaged the MySQL `root` password, just hit enter when asked for the password, alternatively is you have chnaged the `root` password enter the actual password at the prompt.

Then enter this command at he `mysql>` prompt to run you restore of you backup file

```
source C:/path/to/your/backup.sql
```

This has not limits on execution time or file size.